# Schedule SSIS solution

Tags: sql, ssis, etl

How can I schedule to execute my SSIS ETL solution (not the individual packages separately)?

Comment: This is not a request I've heard of before. Are you intending to run all the packages in the solution at once? Can you expand on why you want to do this, it doesn't really make sense to me

Comment: Sorry, I'll try to give you some context :-) . I had some forma training in Business Intelligence and just starting to put it into practice in my new job. ETL wise, in formal training in university, I've learned to prepare a solution with different packages and different containers determining which packages would run in paralell and which would run after the previous container. What I've found in my company implemented is something different... Is a package with a loop (scheduled to run every morning) to run in sequence all staging packages and then all dimension packages and then all facts.

Comment: Yep so there is a single master package that runs a bunch of child packages. That is normal practice. You just schedule the master package. There's no concept of scheduling a "project". A project is just something that collects all packages that have a common purpose or development life cycle.

Comment: I would like to move the different packages to a solution where I could manage them more easilty with shared variables and reduce processing time by defining some packages to run in paralell, but if I do so, then I would not know how to schedule that solution to run automatically every morning - that's what I'm looking for. Does that make sense?

Comment: Is there a master package that actually runs the SSIS solution?

Comment: _a package with a loop (scheduled to run every morning) to run in sequence all staging packages and then all dimension packages and then all facts_ Do you mean this is a master package that only runs stuff in sequence and you want to run various things in parallel. If you know that you can run things in parallel you have two options: 1. Enhance the existing package so that you can tell it to run certain packages in parallel; 2. Create a "static" package that explicitly defines what packages run when,

Comment: _Is there a master package that actually runs the SSIS solution_ No. In your solution you can define a "startup package" but I think this is only for debugging.... and doesn'r seem to work properly anywyay https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/selecting-start-launches-the-wrong-ssis-package/142623

Comment: The fact is you need to define which packages run in parallel and in which order and saying "run solution" doesn't define this. You either explicitly define the packages in a master package as you learnt previously or you enhance the existing approach to deine which package runs in what order and in parallel. BTW I have done this before many years ago. I suggest you edit your existing question with all these details and explain more carefully how the existing approach works and what you want to change about it (as I am making assumptions here)

Comment: _ if I do so, then I would not know how to schedule that solution to run automatically every morning_ you need to create a seperate master package (inside the existing solution) that contains the definition of what runs sequentially and what runs in parallel (i.e. all dimensions usually run in parallel at the start) then schedule that package

Comment: Thansk for all your help! I'll try to adjust the current master (loop) package to fulfil the paralell running. Still, it seems odd that I can define all that sequence process in a solution and run it manually, but if I want to schedule it, I need to redefine the same things in a master package... It just seems double work... I'm not getting the reason for that, but maybe is just some dumb questions from someone that's just starting and not seeing the full picture :-)

Comment: _it seems odd that I can define all that sequence process in a solution and run it manually_ how do you do that? Are you saying you can press play in Visual Studio and the packages run in a specified order every time? I've never seen that. How do you specify the order?

Comment: Quite often with a bunch of packages the execution order and paralelllism is quite complex and you can even have conditional execution requirements. That needs to be defined somewhere. There's no capability to do that in an SSIS solution so you do it in a master package..... or you come up with an execution framework where you define it in a table (soudsm like this is what you have).

Comment: Oh, I've got it now! My terminology was wrong, that's the confusion! You can have a package with a control flow with different tasks and containers, ans then the different tasks - I was calling the solution that package and calling the packages the individual tasks! Because in my company they had made each task as a different package and then a package with a loop to run all the others and I want to put all tasks together in a single package to manage the full ETL process together!

Comment: In the current process, if I would update a connection, I would have to go the each individual package with a single task to update it (makes no sense!).

Comment: It sounds like you can bring some improvements to their process just make sure you fully understand any repercussions of changes and make a backup (even better put it in Git)